# Compute the mean of some data in a data frame, based on their quartile allocated in another data frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with some values (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) assigned to a quartile for each month:

```
          a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h
         ---------------------------------  
2019-01 | 1   2   3   1   3   4   4   2 
2019-02 | 2   3   1   1   4   4   3   2
2019-03 | 3   2   2   3   1   4   1   4
```

And another dataframe with the monthly return of each value

```
          a      b     c     d     e     f     g     h
         ----------------------------------------------- 
2019-01 | 0.4   0.7   0.1   0.3   0.4   0.4   0.1   0.1
2019-02 | 0.2   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.4   0.1   0.7   0.8 
2019-03 | 0.3   0.4   0.2   0.3   0.1   0.2   1.1   0.7
```

My objective is to create a new dataframe with the monthly mean return of each quartile, with the data above, it should look like this:

```
           1       2      3      4   
         ----------------------------
2019-01 | 0.35   0.40    0.25   0.25  
2019-02 | 0.10   0.50    0.40   0.25  
2019-03 | 0.60   0.30    0.30   0.45
```

It might be a simple question, but I am new at R and after been working on it for a while now, I can't figure out how to do it.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi. welcome to SO, please add a good reprex, this can be easy using the dput function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `tapply` from `base R`.  Convert the second dataset to `matrix` (`as.matrix`), use the `row` index and the values in first dataset as groups, and get the `mean`

```
out <- t(tapply(as.matrix(df2), list(as.matrix(df1), row(df1)), FUN = mean))
row.names(out) <- row.names(df1)
```

-output

```
out
#           1   2    3    4
#2019-01 0.35 0.4 0.25 0.25
#2019-02 0.10 0.5 0.40 0.25
#2019-03 0.60 0.3 0.30 0.45
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   rownames_to_column('date') %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -date) %>% 
   left_join(df2 %>%
             rownames_to_column('date') %>% 
             pivot_longer(cols = -date, values_to = 'value2')) %>% 
   group_by(date, value) %>%
   summarise(value2 = mean(value2), .groups = 'drop') %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = value2) %>%
   column_to_rownames("date")
```

-output

```
#          1   2    3    4
#2019-01 0.35 0.4 0.25 0.25
#2019-02 0.10 0.5 0.40 0.25
#2019-03 0.60 0.3 0.30 0.45
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = 1:3, b = c(2L, 3L, 2L), c = c(3L, 1L, 2L), 
    d = c(1L, 1L, 3L), e = c(3L, 4L, 1L), f = c(4L, 4L, 4L), 
    g = c(4L, 3L, 1L), h = c(2L, 2L, 4L)), class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c("2019-01", 
"2019-02", "2019-03"))

df2 <- structure(list(a = c(0.4, 0.2, 0.3), b = c(0.7, 0.1, 0.4), c = c(0.1, 
0.1, 0.2), d = c(0.3, 0.1, 0.3), e = c(0.4, 0.4, 0.1), f = c(0.4, 
0.1, 0.2), g = c(0.1, 0.7, 1.1), h = c(0.1, 0.8, 0.7)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("2019-01", 
"2019-02", "2019-03"))
```